# Ticket for Universal Studios LA - Online or Physical

Tags: los-angeles, universal-studios

I am going to visit LA in coming weekend. Is there any benefit to buy the admission ticket online, compared to physically? And also, do the tickets get over if I wait until the last day?

Comment: I don't understand "do the tickets get over if I wait until the last day." Do you mean, "Do I need to buy tickets well in advance to make sure I get one?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 Primary Benefits [clearly stated by them](https://store.universalstudioshollywood.com/PurchaseTickets.aspx)

- Save vs Front Gate
- Early Park Admission
- Guarantee Your Date

Comment: Also, you only need to queue once to enter the park.